Quarto Hypothesis
I am using Quarro & RStudio to develop a document.  My question is, how would I be able to create a referenceable Hypothesis similar to the native functionality of theorems (see here.
I tried using a .lua file but it didn't work.
local hypothesis_counter = 1
local hypothesis_label = "Hypothesis" 

function Div(div)
  if div.classes[1] == "hypothesis" then
    local title = div.content[1].text
    local description = div.content[2].text -- Extract description text

    -- Construct the single-line content
    local content = pandoc.Strong(hypothesis_label .. " " .. hypothesis_counter .. ": ")
    content:insert(pandoc.Space())
    content:insert(pandoc.Span(title)) 
    content:insert(pandoc.Space())
    content:insert(pandoc.Span(description))

    -- Replace the div content with the single-line version
    div.content = {content}

    hypothesis_counter = hypothesis_counter + 1
  end
  return div
end


If I am reading your question right, this can be done easily with Quarto's custom cross-reference syntax. Read that link for more details on this functionality. For example as a PDF:
---
format: pdf
crossref:
  custom:
    - key: hyp
      kind: float
      reference-prefix: Hypothesis
      latex-env: hypothesis # This is required if you are using PDF format
---

This is some text prior to our custom cross-reference.

::: {#hyp-test}

## My Research Question

I hypothesize that A will cause B

:::

This is some text after the cross-reference, see @hyp-test above

Produces the following document:


Yes!  This meets the requirement partially.  I would like the hypothesis to be structured as:  Hypothesis (#) (Hypothesis Title) (Actual Description of Hypothesis); for example:
Hypothesis 1 (Density Dependence) As the number of organisations grows, the mortality hazard declines to a certain point.
Additionally, when I remove the title "my research question" it doesn't work properly.

To clarify: your goal is to do this for a PDF format, correct?

Presently, yes.  Long-term it would be nice if the same can be achieved for HTML.  This enables me to maintain a flexible repository of my articles irrespective of its final format (HTML or PDF).
